# CocoaPods UIImageView+AFNetworking.h unrecognized selector setImageWithURLRequest

Tags: ios, xcode5, afnetworking, cocoapods, objective-c-category

I have installed **AFNetworking 2.1.0** with **CocoaPods** on Xcode 5.

```
//ViewController.h
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>
```

Calling **setImageWithURLRequest** on an UIImageview the application fail with this log:

This is the error log:

```
2014-02-07 11:55:19.984 OPS[1717:60b] *** Terminating app 
due to uncaught exception'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[UIImageViewsetImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147b06d0'
```

I've found some discussion on this issue, but the provided solution (adding **-ObjC -all_load**) not working in my case.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Are you maybe missing a space in your method call? Which version of AFNetworking do you use?

Comment: I am using AFNetworking 2.1.0. 

No space are missing, in fact the error is at runtime and not at compile time

Comment: Did you try the simpler [yourImageView setImageWithURL:theImageURL]; ?

Comment: could you add your code snippet? And did you try updating the latest cocoa pods and running pod install again?

Comment: Can you NSLog your [imageView class]? Just to make sure that at runtime it's actually a UIImageView and it's not pointing to something else

Comment: Ok.
This is the code:
`NSURL* url= [NSURL URLWithString:exposedSubject.photoUrl];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
        [cell.ExposedSubjectImageView setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {          
}`

Using NSLog the imageView is an [imageView class]

Comment: I have also updated cocoapods and reinstalled the pods

Comment: an imageView class? Should be a UIImageView class but I think you wanted to say that..

Comment: Yes, sorry! The class is UIImageView

Comment: I have noticed the same issue with another library (**tapkulibrary**).

I suppose this problem is related with **Categories** and **Cocoapods**   .

Comment: Have you tried this?

#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"

Comment: Yes and it doesn't fix the problem. I think the problem are the project configurations, because I have updated the project using CocoaPods. I will try to create a new clean project and then import all the code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same problem with **Xcode 5**, **Cocoapods** and **AFNetworking 1.3.3**.

I found my answer in this Google Groups discussion: [AFNetworking unrecognized selector](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocoapods/dLi0dLn6K9o)

> Make sure your project and target settings aren't overwriting the values in the xcconfig file.
>
> Each level should have (at least) **$(inherited)** to inherit the settings of the parent.

In Build Settings, make sure you have `$(inherited)` in Other Linker Flags.

Build Settings before I added `$(inherited)` (choose Levels, not Combined):

[image: Other Linker Flags without $(inherited)]

Build Settings after I added `$(inherited)`:

[image: Other Linker Flags with $(inherited)]

That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem.

I have tried this fix before but I have added $(inherited) only in the Project but not in the Target.

Comment: This solved my problem! It worked changing just in target. Double click on on Other Linker Flags (your project name tab ) and add $(inherited)

Comment: Huge thanks to you! CocoaPods warned me about this, but I didn't actually know that you can keep your existing flags and use $(inherited) with them. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the above solutions didn't fix it.  It was a stupid mistake.  I only included the .h, instead of both .h and .m

Answer (score -1):

Check the PodFile. May be it is setting the instlalation "pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'" for another target.